# Wrong filename encoding with PhpStorm / WinSCP and SFTP

Tags: encoding, utf-8, phpstorm, sftp

My hoster has disabled FTP so I am forced to use SFTP but I encountered some strange issues with PhpStorm since moving to SFTP. My filenames sometimes have german umlauts in them like `Lösungsblatt` or `Übungsblatt` and usually it was uploaded properly and the host window displayed the files correctly. Since I am forced to use SFTP old files on the remote host show up as this

[image]

while newly uploaded files display correctly inside PhpStorm. However in WinSCP the old files are displayed correctly as `Lösungsblatt-01.pdf` etc. but the files which seemed to be uploaded correctly via PhpStorm are broken since they show up as

[image]

which is basically the other way round. I do have a feeling that UTF-8 and UTF-16 filenames are being mixed in the process of uploading so I was curious as to how I can setup the IDE to (1) show the filenames in the remote tree properly and (2) upload files properly with the right encoding (not the encoding of the content but the encoding of the filename itself!)

Answer (score 0):

In SFTP protocol file names have to be in UTF-8. Though actually that's only since version 4. The older versions did not mandate a specific encoding. So implementations vary. Some use UTF-8, but many (maybe most) use the default encoding of the system (like the default Windows Ansi encoding).

Recent version of WinSCP always use UTF-8, even for servers implementing SFTP version 3 (or older), like the OpenSSH. Actually OpenSSH does not have a view on the encoding. It uses whatever encoding the underlying system uses. As most *nix systems default to UTF-8 these days, it just works.

My guess is that PhpStorm actually uses the default Ansi encoding of Windows (what would be Windows-1252 for "Western languages"). You can force WinSCP to use that too by setting the ["UTF-8 encoding for filenames"](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_environment#utf) to "Off". Though you should actually force PhpStorm to use UTF-8.